# Python interpreter defining variable as tulpe when it's a string?

Tags: python, concatenation

I found this code on the internet, meant to search through text files in a zipped folder to find matches. I ran it in IDLE to see how it worked.. but I have a problem, and it seems to be this line:

```
fname = seed + ".txt"
```

The error message returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/[name]/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/zip2.py", line 10, in <module>
fname = seed + ".txt"
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Here is the code:

```
import re
from zipfile import *
findnothing = re.compile(r"Next nothing is (\d+)").match
comments = []
z = ZipFile("channel.zip", "r")

seed = "90052"

while True:
    fname = seed + ".txt"
    comments.append(z.getinfo(fname).comment)
    guts = z.read(fname)
    m = findnothing(guts.decode('utf-8'))
    if m:
        seed = m.groups(1)
    else:
        break
 print("".join(comments))
```

I've searched stackoverflow, and have found nothing similar to my issue. Most of them state that a comma in a variable usually causes the compiler to treat it as a tuple. I don't understand why it is saying seed is a tuple. There is no comma, no parenthesis, or anything else that would define it as a tuple to the Python compiler. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `m.groups(1)` to `m.group(1)` (singular, not plural).  Per the docs at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.match.groups , `group` returns a single match but `groups` returns a tuple of all matches.  You are getting the error the second time through the loop, when `seed` has been replaced by the output of `groups`, which is a tuple.

Comment: Thanks for your response and the link to the docs! I changed the code, and it no longer throws an error when concatenating the strings.  However, I ended up with a different error, that I managed to solve by myself. I'll put my solution here in case anyone else encounters a similar situation.  The last line of code returned "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found"    I fixed it by changing the code  to "print(str(b"".join(comments)))"

Answer (score 1):

First, `re.match` only matches at the start of the string. Make sure you didn't mean to use `re.search` instead!

Second, `m.groups(1)` returns a tuple like `('12345',)`. Try `seed = m.groups(1)[0]` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response! You say that re.match only matches at the start of the string, and to make sure I didn't mean to use re.search instead.. the text files this program is meant to search through only have one line each. Is re.search still a more appropriate choice for this case?